# Deconflict Twitter Bootstrap with other CSS and JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I found a good template with some neat CSS, but my previous code for the main interface uses a lot of Twitter Bootstrap (3). However there is a lot of conflicts between them, primary one I can not seem to fix is drop down menu.

Is there a way to override or isolate Bootstrap or bridge it for the drop down menus. 
Yes I know there should be more creative object names, but both CSS come with very deep rooted names so changing it is fairly problematic.

HTML is as follows

```
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>Option</li>
     <li><span>DropDown</span>
      <ul>
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
   </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Bootstrap does not style `nav` elements that do not have the `.navbar` class assigned to them.

So, if you happen to use `nav` with the same bootstrap class name `.navbar`, you'll have to override the `.navbar` rules (in addition to its child elements `ul` and `li`).

Comment: hmm strange, there is no .navbar class in the nav but is still not styled properly
it get styled like links for some reason, but answer does make sense just not this case right now